# ng-repeat | filter: Inline inequalities?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

For Angular's `ng-repeat`, I only saw inline *equality* filters. However, is it possible to inline inequalities as well?

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DLYys/) illustrates my problem:

```html
Equality filter works:
<div ng-controller="repeatCtrl">
   <div ng:repeat="o in list | filter: id = myPrecious.id">
       {{o.id}}: 
       <input type="checkbox" ng:model="o.checked" />
       {{o.checked}}
    </div>
</div>

<hr />

Inequality filter does not work:
<div ng-controller="repeatCtrl">
   <div ng:repeat="o in list | filter: id != myPrecious.id">
       {{o.id}}: 
       <input type="checkbox" ng:model="o.checked" />
       {{o.checked}}
    </div>
</div>
```

[The documentation for ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) leaves **MUCH** to be desired. Are inline inequality filters possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with Angular string manipulation. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DLYys/4/) shows a working solution.

The trick is to use `{someProp: '!' + someVariable}`:

```
ng:repeat="o in list | filter: {id : '!' + myPrecious.id}"
```

I have yet to find a proper reference for the Angular filter syntax though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes please see here : http://jsfiddle.net/DLYys/1/

```
<div ng-controller="repeatCtrl">
   <div ng:repeat="o in list | filter: {id : !myPrecious.id}">
       {{o.id}}: 
       <input type="checkbox" ng:model="o.checked" />
       {{o.checked}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but for some stupid reason I just assumed that this would work, so I marked this as "answered". However, it actually does not work... Please check your fiddle.

Comment: Hi Domi, that happens because filter not interpolating  'myPrecius.id' and in this case you have to create your own function to filter array please see there http://jsbin.com/ruvohije/3/edit

Comment: That's because this syntax seems to only allow for constants, and it does not get interpreted as an interpolant. Obviously, that does not answer my question either then. Do you know of a reference manual for the complete `filter` syntax somewhere?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out ([see below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24285561/2228771)). But I am still looking for that reference manual.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it like this

```
$scope.someLogic = function(item) {
    return ($scope.myPrecious.id !== item.id);
};



BAD:
<div ng-controller="repeatCtrl">
   <div ng:repeat="o in list | filter: someLogic">
       {{o.id}}: 
       <input type="checkbox" ng:model="o.checked" />
       {{o.checked}}
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AnandVishnu/KwF6N/)

Comment: That is not quite as *inline* as I wanted it to be. I.e. the filter logic is not in the `filter:` line.

Comment: Yes, this method would be more useful when the logic gets more complex and can not be done in single line

Comment: Not what I asked for, sorry.

Comment: Turns out the other answer is also not correct. Do you know how to inline this? Or do you know where the complete documentation on Angular filters is, that covers all these special cases?

Comment: @anand as some other guy, can confirm it was useful for me